# How to assess students in real analysis?

Tags: undergraduate-education, exams, mathematical-analysis, assessment

Terence Tao says the following in the preface to his book Analysis I:

> With regard to examinations for a course based on this text, I would recommend either an open-book, open-notes examination with problems similar to the exercises given in the text (but perhaps shorter, with no unusual trickery involved), or else a take home examination that involves problems comparable to the more intricate exercises in the text. The subject matter is too vast to force the students to memorize the definitions and theorems, so I would not recommend a closed-book examination, or an examination based on regurgitating extracts from the book. (Indeed, in my own examinations I gave a supplemental sheet listing the key definitions and theorems which were relevant to the examination problems.)

Based on Tao's comments, we can separate the most common types of examination into the following categories:

1. Closed-book/closed-notes examination without supplemental sheet.
2. Closed-book/closed-notes examination with supplemental sheet.
3. Open-book/open-notes examination.
4. Home examination.

**Based on your experience (or on sources on the subject that you know), in the context of real analysis examination:

(a) What is the best category?

(b) What are the pros and cons?

(c) How similar should the exam questions be to the homework questions?**

If you use a different category from those listed above, feel free to comment.

*Addendum:* I'm talking about an introductory course that covers the basics of natural and real numbers, convergence of sequences and series, limits of functions, continuity, derivatives, integrals, sequences and series of functions.

Comment: It really depends on the abilities of your students.  If I gave an open-book/open-notes examination of the type Professor Tao imagines, more than half of my students (even those who study quite hard) would be able to answer zero questions - they have no ability to apply what they have learned to situations that are not exactly the same as those they have been explicitly taught to work in.

Comment: Adding to what @AlexanderWoo said, remember that Tao is at UCLA, which has a world class mathematics department, and is incredibly selective about the students it takes on.  Tao's students are, on average, the best of the best of the best.  What works at UCLA may or may not work elsewhere.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I completely understand that Tao's students are among the brightest in the world. However, his comment does not appear to be restricted to exceptional groups. He seems to address all those who choose to use his book. And as his book can be considered more "basic" or "easy" in some aspects, I believe his recommendation can also be applied to broader classes. Of course, I'm not going to replicate a UCLA test in my class. But perhaps the open-material or supplemental sheet approach might be a good idea. But I'm not sure.

Comment: My point was not that an open-notes approach is either a good idea or a bad idea.  My point is that Tao likely suffers a bit from the curse of knowledge, and that his recommendations might not work for everyone.  In particular, UCLA students tend to *already* understand that they have to memorize a great deal of information, thus basic "regurgitation" questions should be gimmes for those students.  My students (calculus, not analysis---we don't go that far here) need exam problems which do require some rote work, since no one has ever made them memorize *anything* before.

Comment: I tend to ask Tao-style questions in the homework though out the semester.  Most of my students don't even bother to *attempt* them, let alone provide full answers (which is fine---I mark these as the problems that students seeking an A should attempt, and not everyone cares to get an A).  Putting them on an exam would be cruel, with or without notes.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Tao's advice is specifically to proof-based courses (analysis); it doesn't apply, and was not intended for, procedure-based courses like what you're referring to.

Comment: @SRobertJamesI gave calculus as an example.  I am, in fact, aware of the difference.  But the point remains:  students in upper division, proof-based courses need have command over basic facts (i.e. there is a memorization component) *and* they need to be able to produce novel arguments.  Some students will come into such a class already knowing that they need to learn certain things by rote (so asking those students to regurgitate facts is perhaps not helpful), but others will not (so reinforcing that they need to learn the facts should be emphasized in assessment).

Comment: At a place like UCLA, it is probably safe to assume that all (or nearly all) of the students in an analysis class already know that they need to drill and kill, so one can focus on the more interesting problems.  At the kind of institution where I did my masters work (a state university which, at the time, did not have a PhD program in mathematics), students need the "nudge" of assessments which include more basic (i.e. closer to the bottom of Bloom's taxonomy) problems.  There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: (At my masters institution, I would recommend splitting an exam into two parts:  one focusing on regurgitation, which necessarily be closed notes; and another focusing on more novel problems, which would be open notes (but likely not take home).  But, again, this is *highly* dependent on the population of students who are being assessed.)

Comment: @XanderHenderson: You stressed a few times that some students already knew that they had to rote learn some things. I'm a bit surprised, because I don't think that I have ever rote learnt anything when I was a math student and I also discourage my students from doing so. Could you give an example of something that you think should be rote learnt and why?

Comment: @JochenGlueck Times tables are my general first example.  In an intro calculus class in which most of the students are non-majors, certain differentiation and integration rules should be made automatic, either by rote learning or through repetition (the derivative of a constant is zero; the power rule; the product rule; etc).  The derivative of the exponential is itself.  Many definitions need to be memorized.  Perhaps "by rote" is not quite the right word here, but there are a lot of skills which need to be practiced and drilled to the point of automaticity.

Comment: But, again, the point is that at a lot of institutions, you have students who have previously been successful in school, and have *already* developed good skills for college learning.  This is not universally true---most of my students are blown away by the idea that they might have to do work outside of class (let alone 9+ hours per week).  Many students require scaffolding at the lower levels of Bloom's Taxonomy.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Thanks for your reply! I agree, of course, with your main point that different students come to college/university with very different levels of preparation. I also agree that some things need to become automatic after a while. I'm not so convinced about the way how you describe that this process should take place (it doesn't matter so much to me whether we speak of "rote learning" or "drilling" lor "memorizing" - those words all cause similar connotations in my head). But probably this is a topic for another discussion (or stack exchange question).

Comment: By "home exam" do you mean "unproctored"? Proctored/unproctored is a different axis from open-/closed-book and with/without supplemental sheet. My university gave closed-book/note exams that were unproctored; we had a well defined and strictly enforced honor code.

Comment: @shoover I meant a list of problems (probably more difficult, with no available solutions in the book) to be solved as homework.

Comment: @shoover: "*we had a well defined and strictly enforced honor code.*" I assume that this honor code said that cheating is forbidden. How can this be strictly enforced when the exams are unproctored? (By the way I'm also wondering what's the point of an "honor code" that only works because it is strictly enforced.)

Comment: I primarily tutor.  I think anyone offering take home exams underestimates the number of students who are just desperate to pass and have given up on actually learning the exercises.  I regularly get requests, "Will you do this exam for me?"  Many or most exercises, can be googled.  Even if it's a totally unique question, the student can simply post it on MSE and likely get an excellent answer.  An honor code in this situation only put the honest students at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the rules of assessment are the same for every discipline, calculus not excluded, and can be just derived from first principles and your particular version of common sense without any help from Terence Tao. Mine are the following:

1. Decide on a few (3-5) topics you want to test and create one problem for each. Don't give more than 5 problems for a one hour test or include problems that require long solutions with extensive computations.
2. Tell the students that the exam will be concentrated on these topics and give them sufficient number of practice problems well before the test.
3. Out of 5 problems make 3 completely routine (for the students who know the subject, of course), 1 with a minor twist and 1 really hard (though requiring nothing beyond the covered material).
4. Invent your problems from scratch and tune them up exactly to your satisfaction yourself.
5. Conduct the exam in a fully controlled environment (ideally in a classroom with your own presence).
6. Grade on some simple scale with minimal partial credit (mine is 6 - full solution, 5-a solution with minor error, 1-just a good idea, 0-everything else; occasionally I do give the scores of 4 and 2, but those are exceptions).

Whether it is open or closed book/notes doesn't matter too much as long as you understand that each of those kinds of exams just requires a different tune-up of the problems. I never give take home exams to undergraduates though: tuning those up properly would require creating open problems based on the elementary calculus material. That *is* possible, but the most likely outcome will be that nobody will solve anything. Everything short of that will result in shameless cheating and total mayhem with grading, IMHO.

Needless to say, this is just *my* approach based on *my* common sense. Your common sense may be totally different. Just follow it and don't be afraid to experiment with various formats. Whatever works to your satisfaction is the right way, whatever doesn't is the wrong one. It is always as simple as that.

Just my 2 cents :-)